# How to append to a variable in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var golden_site = '<div id="golden_site"></div>';
$('.form_content').append(golden_site);
var lookup = '<input type="text" name="lookup" value="test">';
```

Why is this not working:

```
$(golden_site).append(lookup);
```

But accessing the node by id works:

```
$('#golden_site').append(lookup);
```

Comment: The norm is to select elements using ID's or class names. I'm pretty sure that's how javascript works so does Jquery.

Comment: That is because `golden_site` is not a DOM node, but simply a HTML string. You're appending content to a HTML string, but not into the DOM.

Comment: Another Reason is, look how long your golden_site string is. What if you had styles in it. that would be one really long string to find on the page. So using Id's make the Job simpler. Probably the reason why JS is built that way. Imagine how big your Javascript files would be if we had the approach you are using.

Comment: @Tasos: When you call jQuery with a HTML fragment, it won't try to find it in the page. It creates elements from it.

Comment: @Guffa I was trying to say that if you could do it that way, you script files would be 10 times larger than using simple id or class names to select elements. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `$('#golden_site')` selects the div with `id=golden_site`. While this `$(golden_site)` doesn't select anything.

Taken from [here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/), you have the following ways of selecting an element using jQuery

- Selecting Elements by ID
- Selecting Elements by Class Name
- Selecting Elements by Attribute
- Selecting Elements by Compound CSS Selector
- Pseudo-Selectors

The way you tried to select your `div` doesn't follow one of the above ways. Hence you didn't make it. While using the id you made it, since this is included in the above ways.

**update**

As Guffa pointed out (I didn't now it) in his comment,

> The call $(golden_site) doesn't try to use the string as a selector at
>   all. It will create an elements from the HTML string, and actually
>   return that element

Comment: why not? I have defined a variable for it? `var golden_site = '<div id="golden_site"></div>';` I recon because its just a string. So it wont work like that.

Comment: Yes you have a variable named `golden_site`, which is a string.  Thus jQuery is using your string to find a matching element on the page.  There are no elements that selector engine can match your string because it is invalid as a selector.  IE:  `$('<div id="golden_site"></div>')` will not return any elements.

Comment: That's not correct. The call `$(golden_site)` doesn't try to use the string as a selector at all. It will create an elements from the HTML string, and actually return that element.

Comment: @Guffa thank you ! I didn't now that. I will edit my answer asap.

Answer (score 1):

The code is working fine, but it doesn't do what you think.

The `$(golden_site)` part will create a new `div` element from the HTML code in the string. The `lookup` element will then be appended to that `div`. As the `div` is an element that you just created, it's not in the page and the `lookup` element that you appended to it isn't in the page either.

If you create the `div` element first and then append that to the page, instead of using a string in the `append`, then you have a reference to the `div` element:

```
var golden_site = '<div id="golden_site"></div>';
var element = $(golden_site);
$('.form_content').append(element);
```

Now you can append things to it:

```
element.append(lookup);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when you say

```
$(golden_site).append(lookup);
```

Actually you mean:

```
'<div id="golden_site"></div>'
```

In plain words, it's just a string, not a jQuery object that can be appended to. *golden_site* is just a string.

Comment: The `golden_site` is just a string, but `$(golden_site)` actually returns a jQuery object, and it can actually be appended to. It's just that the element in it isn't in the page.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the `$()` is in fact a wrapper of jQuery over the `document.querySelector()`. So as expected both methods should behave similar, when you do:

```
$("#blah").append(x);
```

Indeed the browser is doing this:

```
document.querySelector("#blah").appendChild(x);
```

So both methods should work as they explain here -> [How query Selector works](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp)

As you can see the variable passed as argument is a string that will be used as a **CSS Selector**, they explain here -> [CSS Selector List](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

I will add this graphic with some of the most common ways to select elements from the DOM, don't forget the `''`, courtesy from W3CSchools.

[image: CSS Selector List]

Comment: When the string passed to the `$` function is a HTML fragment, then the function doesn't work as a wrapper for `querySelector`. Instead it will create elements from the string.